# MS-Access: I can't figure out why the error message is not showing up

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2010

I am building a database for cancer research purposes. I have created a form called "inputPI_form". PI stands for "Principal Investigator" aka researcher. tblPI is just a table with first names and last names.

Here is my form:

[image]

When you click the "save" button, you run the bottom code.

I have created a composite key in tblPI using both names to prevent any duplicate record. This code prevents duplicate records, but there is no MsgBox showing up:

```
'Add new PI's name and verify uniqueness with composite key'
Private Sub newPI_Button_Click()

   'Declare duplication error number'
   Const ERR_DUPLICATE_VALUE = 3022

   On Error GoTo Err_Handler

   'Declare database object and string variables'
   Dim dbs As Database
   Dim firstName As String
   Dim lastName As String

   'Capture firstName and lastName from inputPI_form as strings'
   firstName = Forms("inputPI_form")!firstName.Value
   lastName = Forms("inputPI_form")!lastName.Value

   'Set the dbs object'
   Set dbs = CurrentDb

  'Excute SQL code to create new record in tblPI by passing firstName and lastName values'
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tblPI (lastName, FirstName) VALUES " & _
    "('" & lastName & "','" & firstName & "');"

  'Update the PI selection combobox on inputProtocolForm'
  Forms("inputProtocolForm")!selectionPI.Requery

  dbs.Close
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "inputPI_form"

Err_Handler:
  If Err.Number = ERR_DUPLICATE_VALUE Then
     MsgBox ("This PI's name is already taken. Please select another one.")
  End If
End Sub
```

I am not familiar in catching errors in VBA. Am I making an obvious mistake? I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Try simplifying your Error Handler.  Take out the If statement and replace it was a simple `Msgbox Err.number & Err.description`. Did you get what you expected?

Comment: Actually,  it did!! So simple! If you post your answer, I'll chose it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Some additional notes: 1. Watch out what happens if you enter a last name `O'Neil`. 2. It can happen that two people have the same first + last name. This is not really a suitable unique key.

Comment: @Andre Thank you for your feedback! I would greatly appreciate any idea! How could I still use both names, but circumvent this problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying your Error Handler. Take out the If statement and replace it was a simple Msgbox Err.number & Err.description. Did you get what you expected?